# React Does Not Re-Render after useEffect and useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

React won't rerender after `useEffect` axios response updates state with `useState`. The query works, and if I click to another endpoint and back again, it does render successfully, but it doesn't successfully render on mount.

This is an expensive query so I just want to run it once when the website is loaded or refreshed.

```js
const App: React.FC = () => {
    const [cards, setCards] = useState<Card[]>([]);

    // query server for list of cards on mount
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("http://localhost:3001/cards")
            .then(response => setCards(response.data))
            .catch(error => alert(`Error fetching cards. ${error}`))
    }, []);

    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<LandingPage cards={cards} />} />
            {/* This does not show all cards! */}
            {cards.map((card, idx) => <Route key={idx} path={'/' + card.endpoint} element={<Card card={card}/>} />)}
        </Routes>
    )
}
```

Comment: State updates will be reflected only on the component's next render, you can't log a state just after setting it and expect to see the changes immediately reflected.

Comment: @ivanatias thanks for the comment! So do I need to somehow force a re-render after the axios request completes?

Comment: log the response.data in your axios to see if data is being fetched correctly

Comment: @bgcodes it is being fetched correctly

Comment: instead of rendering <Route> component just render <div key={idx}>{card.endpoint}</div> just to see if state is being updated

Comment: ...and can we see what response.data looks like?

Answer (score 1):

First things first, you should add a key to each element of your map function to render the Route components correctly. This will also help to force a re-render of that component whenever the keychanges. Let's try that first and see what happens

Also, the `console.log(cards)` after your `setCards(response.data)` won't print because the state update operation hasn't been finished yet

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. Added key, see original post. Still not re-rendering :/